# Traverse through binary tree

Tags: rust, binary-tree

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct TreeNode {
    pub val: i32,
    pub left: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>,
    pub right: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>,
}

impl TreeNode {
    #[inline]
    pub fn new(val: i32) -> Self {
        TreeNode {
            val,
            left: None,
            right: None,
        }
    }

    pub fn invalid_path_error(self) {
        panic!("Invalid path");
    }

    pub fn insert(&mut self, directions: &[&str], val: i32) {
        let mut cur_node = &mut None;

        let l = directions.len();

        if directions[0] == "left" {
            cur_node = &mut self.left;
        }
        if directions[0] == "right" {
            cur_node = &mut self.right;
        }

        for dir in &directions[1..] {
            let mut n;

            if *dir == "left" {
                if let Some(z) = cur_node {
                    n = &mut z.borrow_mut().left;
                } else {
                    panic!("Invalid path");
                }
            }
            if *dir == "right" {
                if let Some(z) = cur_node {
                    n = &mut z.borrow_mut().right;
                } else {
                    panic!("Invalid path");
                }
            }

            cur_node = n;
        }

        //cur_node = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(TreeNode::new(2))));
    }
}
```

I am trying to learn rust by solving some leet code questions.  I am trying to implement insert function for binary tree. This is the struct given in leet code. I am trying to implement insert by pass list of strings for path For eg. go left , right , left etc. After traversing at the end I will add new node. I am trying to use cur node as a temp pointer and want to change it with each string. But every time I get this error - " temporary value dropped while borrowed consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value ". How can I fix this and implement insert ?

cargo check -

[image]

Comment: Please always include the full error from `cargo check`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think what you want is possible with `RefCell`. It is possible with other means (e.g. plain ownership with `Box`) or via recursion.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Added full error

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @RadhikaGokani Please upload as text, not as image.

Comment: [Learning Rust with Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/index.html) will answer all of your questions and more, as every "borrow problem" is shown and (mostly) solved there, saying *why* things happen every step of the way.  And it's just fun to read too.

Comment: I agree with @ChayimFriedman; I don't think your implementation is easily fixable. If you decide that you are using `Rc<RefCell<...>>`, you need to keep every `.borrow_mut()` alive while you are iterating through the tree. You can't overwrite `cur_node` because that would drop the parent reference that you still need to borrow child.

Either use `Box<..>` instead of `Rc<RefCell<..>>`, or use recursion, as recursion is capable of keeping the parent variable alive.

Comment: @Finomnis Technically `Vec` should be possible too, but I was unable to use it (not that I put much thought into it, so it might be possible).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman `Vec` sounds like hard overkill for a link based binary tree, though ...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that replaces `Rc<RefCell<_>>` with `Box<_>`. Generally you only need to reach for `Rc` when multiple people will want ownership over the underlying data. In this case, each node is only owned by one other node, so `Box` is preferable.

This solution iterates through the tree to find the last node, then uses the last direction to assign to the correct child node. No checks are implemented to make sure that the nodes along the path exist or that an existing node isn't being overwritten.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct TreeNode {
    pub val: i32,
    pub left: Option<Box<TreeNode>>,
    pub right: Option<Box<TreeNode>>,
}

impl TreeNode {
    #[inline]
    pub fn new(val: i32) -> Self {
        TreeNode {
            val,
            left: None,
            right: None,
        }
    }

    pub fn insert(&mut self, directions: &[&str], val: i32) {
        let mut cur_node = self;

        let len = directions.len();
        let mut directions = directions.into_iter().copied();
        for direction in directions.by_ref().take(len - 1) {
            let child_node = match direction {
                "left" => &mut cur_node.left,
                "right" => &mut cur_node.right,
                _ => panic!("invalid direction {direction}"),
            };
            cur_node = child_node.as_mut().expect("invalid path").as_mut();
        }

        let new_node = Some(Box::new(TreeNode::new(val)));
        match directions.next().unwrap() {
            "left" => cur_node.left = new_node,
            "right" => cur_node.right = new_node,
            direction @ _ => panic!("invalid direction {direction}"),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut tree = TreeNode::new(0);
    tree.insert(&["left"], 1);
    tree.insert(&["right"], 2);
    tree.insert(&["left", "left"], 2);
    tree.insert(&["right", "left"], 3);
    println!("{:#?}", tree);
}
```

Prints

```
TreeNode {
    val: 0,
    left: Some(
        TreeNode {
            val: 1,
            left: Some(
                TreeNode {
                    val: 2,
                    left: None,
                    right: None,
                },
            ),
            right: None,
        },
    ),
    right: Some(
        TreeNode {
            val: 2,
            left: Some(
                TreeNode {
                    val: 3,
                    left: None,
                    right: None,
                },
            ),
            right: None,
        },
    ),
}
```

Comment: Nit: `into_iter()` on slices -> `iter()`. Also, I'd branch on the first and not the last direction: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f2a8229913f9e9b5c422c9fbcfe44329